# Is it forbidden to depict the tzimtzum in art?

Tags: halacha, mysticism-kabbalah, zohar, art

I genuinely am having trouble finding the answer to this. The Zohar has imagery to describe the tzimtzum. E.g. the very start of Bereshit with the Lamp of Darkness. See also Parashat Bo

The imagery itself is easy to depict visually, although of course it is understood to be metaphorical.

The question is, would it be assur in any way to deliberately draw out this imagery as some sort of teaching tool, or art on a Sefer or any other purpose? Any restrictions if no?

Comment: Bonus question, possibly for its own: what if someone wants to use the art because it has a letter that matches their name? E.g. the Yud in parashat Bo because their name is Yehoshua?